# Kibana and Elasticsearch compatibility with Spring Boot Starter

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, kibana

I´m using `Spring Boot Starter 1.2.5` and `Kibana 4.1.1` and getting an error due to incompatible versions.
My question is: How could I update the `Elastic Search` version eventhough I am currently using the latest `Spring Boot Starter`version?

This is most of my POM file:

```
<!--- ... --->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->
</dependencies>
```

I guess that this could be fixed overriding the version number of some of the transitive dependencies of `spring-starter-data-elasticseach` but I have no idea how to do that.

**UPDATE:** I have just made it work by hard-coding the elastic search dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I am not confortable at all with this fix. Is there any other cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What elasticsearch version are you currently using?

Comment: 1.7.0 as per the update above

Comment: I do not have knowledge regarding spring-boot, but i found the pom file which you can check & amend into your POM file.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks Yuvraj. Unfortunatelly I can´t modify that POM file directly, I need to override the version used there.

Comment: I am really sorry. I do not have knowledge regarding it.
BTW i am curious why cannot you modify the POM file?

Comment: Because is a dependency, I don´t either have it or own it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the pom.xml for spring data elasticsearch it injects the version from an "elasticsearch" property:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch}</version>
</dependency>
```

To override the default version you can set this property in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <elasticsearch>1.7.0</elasticsearch>
</properties>
```